# Сравнение кортежей Python

Tags: python

Есть метод для сравнение объектов `Person`

```
def compare_persons_less(person_left, person_right):
    """Return True if left < right."""
    return (-person_left.count_task,person_left.count_fine,person_left.login) > (- 
   person_right.count_task, person_right.count_fine, person_right.login)
```

Выглядит элегантно, но работает медленнее аналога с кучей `if`-ов:

```
def compare_persons_less_2(person_left, person_right):
    """Return True if left < right."""
    if person_left.count_task < person_right.count_task:
        return True
    if person_left.count_task > person_right.count_task:
        return False
    if person_left.count_task == person_right.count_task:
        if person_left.count_fine > person_right.count_fine:
            return True
        if person_left.count_fine < person_right.count_fine:
            return False
        if person_left.count_fine == person_right.count_fine:
            if person_left.login > person_right.login:
                return True
            if person_left.login < person_right.login:
                return False
            if person_left.login == person_right.login:
                return False
```

Вопрос: как сделать так же элегантно, как в первом варианте и также быстро, как во втором?

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(l: 'person_left', r: 'person_left'):
    return (
        l.count_task < r.count_task or
        l.count_fine > r.count_fine or
        l.login > r.login
    )
```

Будет работать как ваш второй вариант, за счет особенности оператора `or`: Как только он встречает истинное значение, сразу же возвращает его, не вычисляя последующие выражения.

Тестил так:

```html
from time import time

class Person:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.count_task, self.count_fine, self.login = a, b, c

def test(fn):
    start = time()
    for _ in range(1000000): fn()
    return time() - start

###
def compare_1(person_left, person_right):
    """Return True if left < right.""" """Return True if left < right."""
    if person_left.count_task < person_right.count_task:
        return True
    if person_left.count_task > person_right.count_task:
        return False
    if person_left.count_task == person_right.count_task:
        if person_left.count_fine > person_right.count_fine:
            return True
        if person_left.count_fine < person_right.count_fine:
            return False
        if person_left.count_fine == person_right.count_fine:
            if person_left.login > person_right.login:
                return True
            if person_left.login < person_right.login:
                return False
            if person_left.login == person_right.login:
                return False

def compare_2(l, r):
    return (
        l.count_task < r.count_task or
        l.count_fine > r.count_fine or
        l.login > r.login
    )

x = Person(1, 2, 3)
y = Person(3, 4, 5)

for _ in range(10):
    print( test(lambda: compare_1(x, y)), test(lambda: compare_2(x, y)) )
```

Comment: _Минутка занудства_: Выразительные названия переменных - хорошо, но не совсем понятно, зачем по всей функции разбрасывать слова `person_left`, если из контекста кода и так понятно, какие это объекты.